# What is the probability for ...?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

You start at the black field bottom left and have to move op til top right black field by only move right and up. 
What is the probability for moving over the white field with the cross in your way to the black field?

By using binomial coefficient I get that the probability is $\frac{35^2}{3432}$. Is that correct?

Comment: You are right. It is equally to move in any of the two directions (right or up).

Comment: I have to laugh to myself that someone voted to close this question as unclear what the OP is asking without making any comments suggesting how the OP can make the question more clear.  Rock solid site moderation right there.

Comment: Explain what is unclear in my qeustion.

Comment: I don't think your question is unclear.  But someone else does (they voted to close the question because of this).  I was commenting that they didn't indicate in any way to you how the question is unclear, and that I don't like that.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the support.

Comment: The question is very unclear without the diagram. You should at least restore the diagram. The question also is not quite mathematical English, but that can be fixed. We usually call this pattern a chessboard, its elements are black and white _squares_, and I think you mean that at each step you move either one square upward with probability $\frac12$ or one square to the right with probability $\frac12$.

Comment: I just deleted the diagram after I got a answer, but I have restored it now. Thanks for the advices!

Comment: The question is ambiguous (even with the diagram...): if, at each step, one chooses to go up or right *when both moves are possible without going out of the board* and if, otherwise, one performs the only legal move, then the answer is not the ratio indicated but rather $$\frac{35}{128}.$$

Comment: How did you get that fraction?

Comment: To summarize the ambiguity, consider the probability to pass by the top-left square A8. Should this be $\binom{7}1\cdot\binom{7}1=1$ in $\binom{14}{7}=3432$, or $1$ over $2^7=128$?

Comment: I believe that the probability is 1 over 3432. Do you agree? Why should it be 1 over $2^7$.

Comment: *This is the question I am asking you*. If your choice is 1 over 3432, talking about random walks was highly misleading. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: Why delete the image *again*?

Comment: That is irrelevant. That is random! There 3432 ways to achieve the top-right black square. There is a probability of 1 over 3432 to choose the way in which you cross A8. Maybe you want to discuss the meaning of random?

Comment: @user46944 Are you still "laugh(ing) to yourself"?

Comment: @Did That was 2 years ago.  I've moved on.

Comment: @user46944 Cool. And maybe your perspective on closure votes has matured somewhat, who knows?

Comment: @Did I respect your enormous contributions to this site, and you've actually helped me out multiple times in the past.  But why does it seem like you're always trying to pick a fight?  Can't we just accept we disagree on these things?  I respect your opinion and your right to voice it, but I don't feel like you feel the same way toward me, given that you suggested my stance on the issue is immature.

Comment: @user46944 Just curious to hear your current opinion (which I still do not know), since I remember having been stunned when, at the time, I read your first comment above. (The rest ("pick a fight" and the like) is just bad pop psychologization.)

Comment: @Did Is it so bad that I expect someone who sees a flaw in a question and votes to close it to at least let OP know what they thought was wrong?  OP isn't always aware of what they are doing wrong.  The voter doesn't have to say "hey I voted to close."  It would be nice if they just said "hey your question is flawed because of so and so, please consider revising asap."  Why is it so wrong for me to want that?

Comment: @user46944 These matters have been discussed to death on meta and no, your take on them is not the only decent one. My suggestion, if I may, would be to first enlarge your horizons about the subject before posting new similar comments.

Comment: @Did I will take your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The total amount of ways to go from the bottom left square to the top right is $\binom{14}{7}=3432$. The amount of ways to go from the bottom left square to the top right that go through the cross is the amount of ways to go from the bottom left to the cross multiplied by the amount of ways to go from the cross to the top left, i.e. $\binom{7}{3}\times\binom{7}{3}=1225(=35^2)$.

So you are right, the probability is $\frac{35^2}{3432}$